# Huawei In App Purchase, implemented everything correctly but still getting the error : authorization format invalid

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to implement Huawei in App Purchase kit to my application.

The request I am sending to the server is here:

```
request {"purchaseToken":"0000017343ec91821b076fd75f71103a5a85595d2dfd245d708fd6058e676f857792b83622c7fd51x434e.1.100059717","productId":"1007"}
```

I am following this guide here : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSInAppPurchase/index.html#0

I am following the same steps but
I am getting an error message from server which says :

```
result: {"responseCode":"6","subErrCode":"211","responseMessage":"6-211-authorization format invalid"}
```

Which part I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you also follow [these instructions](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPreparation/index.html#0) for creating a signing certificate and sign your app during the build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the error you are getting, it says "authorization format invalid". This means your ignature verification data format is invalid. The possible errors might be :

1. The token in the request header is not encrypted in Base64 mode.
2. The character string APPAT is not appended before the access token for authorization. The correct access token is similar to APPAT:thisIsAppAtVaule.

for more information, please check : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/iap-FAQ

Answer (score 2):

You are facing issue in server side. Kindly go through the given link to know more about In App Purchase server side and client side.

**In-App Purchase Article Develioper Forum:**

Client side : https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201255229704010231&fid=0101187876626530001

Server side : https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201273064244120101&fid=0101187876626530001

**In-App Purchase Github Link :**

Client side: https://github.com/DTSE-India-Community/HMS-In-App-Purchase-Kit

Server side:
https://github.com/DTSE-India-Community/Huawei-In-App-Purchase-And-Push-Kit-Server_Side-Implementation